# Nested Cross Validation in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, classification, cross-validation

I am working on a multiclass image classification problem that has 4k labeled images. Currently, I am using `cross-validation`.However, I want to try `nested-cross-validation` for the problem in pytorch but I couldn't find it.

Is it possible to use nested-cross-validation in pytorch? if so, how?

I built a simple pipeline below. Is it correct to implement `nested-cross-validation` like this.

```py
import torch 
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader,SubsetRandomSampler
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from torchvision import datasets

input_size = (256,3,224,244)
target_size = (256,)


class Dataset(datasets.VisionDataset):
    def __init__(self):   
        super().__init__(self)
        self.images = torch.rand(input_size).float()
        self.targets = torch.randint(0,3,target_size)

    def __getitem__(self, index: int) -> any:
        return self.images[index],self.targets[index]

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self.images)

class BasicModel(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super(BasicModel,self).__init__()
        self.conv = torch.nn.Conv2d(3,16,kernel_size=(5,5))
        self.adp = torch.nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d(1)
        self.linear = torch.nn.Linear(16,3)
    
    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.conv(x)
        x = self.adp(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0),-1)
        x = self.linear(x)
        return x

data_ids = [*range(input_size[0])]
data = Dataset()
model = BasicModel()
criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=0.01)

k_fold = 5

kfold_test = KFold(n_splits=k_fold, shuffle=True)
num_epochs = 2

for test_fold,(remain_ids,test_ids) in enumerate(kfold_test.split(data_ids)):

    test_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(test_ids)
    testLoader = DataLoader(data,sampler=test_sampler,batch_size=2)
    
    kfold_val = KFold(n_splits=k_fold-1, shuffle=True)
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        for val_fold,(train_ids,val_ids) in enumerate(kfold_val.split(remain_ids)):
            train_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(train_ids)
            trainLoader = DataLoader(data,sampler=train_sampler,batch_size=2)

            val_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(val_ids)
            valLoader = DataLoader(data,sampler=val_sampler,batch_size=2)

            model.train()
            for image,target in trainLoader:
                with torch.cuda.amp.autocast():
                    output = model(image)
                    loss = criterion(output,target)
                
                optimizer.zero_grad()
                loss.backward()
                optimizer.step()
                print(f"train loss:{loss.item()}")

            model.eval()
            with torch.no_grad():
                for image,target in valLoader:
                    output = model(image)
                    loss = criterion(output,target)
                    print(f"test loss:{loss.item()}")

    model.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
        for image,target in testLoader:
            output = model(image)
            loss = criterion(output,target)
            print(f"test loss:{loss.item()}")
```

Comment: Yes, python is Turing complete; you can execute any arbitrary algorithm with it. I suggest you provide more details and evidence at an initial attempt or your question is likely to be downvoted and closed as it shows little evidence that you put work into solving your question yourself.

Comment: Actually, I don't know how nested-cross-validation works. I am familiar with cross-validation but I still have some difficulties to understand effects of nested-cross-validation on model. So I thought if I try to put a code in the question, it may misslead and also  I don't know how to use parts of inner and outer part in the code.

Comment: Then it seems what you are looking for is an explanation of nested cross validation. Stack overflow probably isn't the best forum for that as there are many existing resources online, e.g. https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/03/a-step-by-step-guide-to-nested-cross-validation/

Comment: Thank you. I'll use the tutorial and try to build one. Then I'll add it to the question or create a new question to add on to be approved whether correct or not

Comment: I added code example to the question